# Rotate ImageView

Tags: java, android

I have roulette (ImageView) with count of scrolls. When I tap on the button once roulette starts to round on 270 degree. When I tap on the button again, roulette must speeds up and round more. How to realise speed up of scrolling after start first animation and decrement count of scrolling after full end of animation?

Comment: Use KeyFrames and timelines with different durations?

Comment: @Sergey, did my solution not point you in the right direction? If not, please post code so I can fix what you are having issues with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having trouble understanding exactly what you want to do as you did not provide any code to reference that shows an error, but this should do what you are asking in terms of allowing your image to rotate faster as you continually click a "rotate" button.

I have used **ObjectAnimator**

**activity_main.xml:**

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_roulette"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Rotation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_roulette"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonStop"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_roulette"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Boolean rotating = false;
    Integer durationOfSpin = 3000; //default 3000

    ImageView image;

    ObjectAnimator animation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_roulette);


        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!rotating) {
                    rotating = true;
                    animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                            image, "rotation", 0, 360);

                    animation.setDuration(durationOfSpin);
                    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                    animation.start();

                }else{
                    if(durationOfSpin - 300 > 0) {
                        durationOfSpin -= 300;   //make slightly faster each subsequent click
                    }
                    animation.setDuration(durationOfSpin);

                }
            }
        });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            //just here so you can cancel your rotation
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(rotating) {
                    rotating = false;
                    durationOfSpin = 3000;      //set back to default
                    animation.cancel();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```